# Call class in function during multiprocessing

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to modify a existing big code to a multiprocessing way. I simplied the question.

Class A is a big external class which I cannot change. I would like to run the class in different cores so I use multiprocessing.Pool. But I got an error as `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fun'` of the line `return input_class.fun(x)`

How can I fix the problem?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

class A(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def fun(self,x):
        return self.value**x

def B(x,input_class):
    return input_class.fun(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = range(10)

    p = Pool(4)

    input_class = A(3)
    input_function = partial(B,input_class)
    op = p.map(input_function,l) 
    print(op)

    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `partial` doesn't do what you want:

```
input_function = partial(B,input_class)
```

This is equivalent to `input_function = lambda input_class__: B(input_class, input_class__)`. So, the *first* argument of the function is now equal to `input_class`, not the second one, and now calls to `input_function` will feed integers as the second argument to `B`, so you'll be getting `<integer>.fun(<input_class>)`.

Change this to:

```
input_function = partial(B, input_class=input_class)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.

And there is another point which is that: class A should be initialised in function B, not just pass to function B. 

It works if I change so.